# why prepend namespace with ::, for example ::std::vector

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have seen production code such as

```
::std::vector<myclass> myvec;
```

I have no idea what the prepending `::` mean however - and why is it used?

For an example see:

[C++: Proper way to iterate over STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925148/c-proper-way-to-iterate-over-stl-containers/4925261#4925261)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leading "::" refers to the global namespace. Suppose you say `namespace foo { ...`. Then `std::Bar` refers to `foo::std::Bar`, while `::std::Bar` refers to `std::Bar`, which is probably what the user meant. So always including the initial "::" can protect you against referring to the wrong namespace, if you're not sure which namespace you're currently in.

Comment: However, std::vector will only refer to foo::std::vector if there actually is one. Highly unlikely! Otherwise it will find ::std::vector anyway.

Comment: @Bo:  No.  For instance, in the example I present below, if you removed the definition of `ns::std::vector`, the declaration of `v1` in `ns::f()` would fail.

Comment: @James: OK, if you actually have a local namespace std without a vector, the compiler will tell you that it is missing. This not a very good reason to **always** use :: in front of everything. If you don't have a local namespace std, the normal std::vector will be found anyway, even if you are in another namespace.

Comment: @Bo:  I agree; it's rare to see names fully qualified, and in general doing so is not necessary.

Comment: @Bo: You're right, I should have said "tries to find" rather than "refers to". Maybe someone can provide a link to a complete description of the scope resolution process.

Comment: Just a working example I came across today - I had some non-namespaced pre-existing code that referred to another namespace without the `::` prefix. I moved this pre-existing code into its own namespace, and that broke all the namespace references - they all needed the `::` prefix added, everywhere. If the original author had used the `::` prefix in the first place it would have been less painful now. Or have I missed something fundamental here?

Comment: @meowsqueak: Well, the problems is with *ambiguities* rather than finding anything at all. The name `foo::x` is looked up first in the context of the current namespace, but then successively in the enclosing namespaces, until a match is found.

Answer (score 23):

This fully qualifies the name, so that only the `vector` template in the `std` namespace in the global namespace is used.  It basically means:

```cpp
{global namespace}::std::vector<myclass> myvec;
```

There can be a difference when you have entities with the same name in different namespaces.  For a simple example of when this could matter, consider:

```cpp
#include <vector>

namespace ns
{
    namespace std
    {
        template <typename T> class vector { };
    }

    void f() 
    { 
        std::vector<int> v1;   // refers to our vector defined above
        ::std::vector<int> v2; // refers to the vector in the Standard Library
    }        
};
```

Since you aren't allowed to define your own entities in the `std` namespace, it is guaranteed that `::std::vector` will always refer to the Standard Library container.  `std::vector` could possibly refer to something else.   .

Comment: It seems there would also be a problem, even if `ns::std` doesn't declare a vector.

Comment: @UncleBens: An excellent point. The `::ns::std` namespace would be found and if it didn't contain an entity named `vector`, name lookup would fail.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that std is not a great choice for normal use cases. It usually would result in confusion on the end-user part.

Answer (score 4):

Taking an example -

```
int variable = 20 ;

void foo( int variable )
{

    ++variable;      // accessing function scope variable
    ::variable = 40;  // accessing global scope variable
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This *always* takes the `vector` from the standard library. `std::vector` might as well be `mycompany::std::vector` if the code where I use it is in namespace `mycompany`.

Comment: So the :: means "the beginning of the namespace tree"?

Comment: Yes. Comments must be at least 15 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with :: means to reset the namespace to global namespace. It might be useful if you're trying to fight some ambiguity in your code.