# What does a leading :: mean in "using namespace ::X" in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

can somebody explain me the difference between the following namespace usages:

`using namespace ::layer::module;`

and

`using namespace layer::module;`

What causes the additional `::` before `layer`?

Comment: This is a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4925394/498253

Comment: @Tom: But is this indeed an exact dupe?

Comment: @sbi: Yep, 'what the prepending :: mean - and why is it used?' but since there are more answers here than there I woudn't close - I just thought the link would be helpful

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There would be a difference if it was used in a context such as:

```
namespace layer {
    namespace module {
        int x;
    }
}

namespace nest {
    namespace layer {
        namespace module {
            int x;
        }
    }
    using namespace /*::*/layer::module;
}
```

With the initial `::` the first `x` would be visible after the using directive, without it the second `x` inside `nest::layer::module` would be made visible.

Answer (score 22):

A leading `::` refers to the ***global namespace***. Any qualified identifier starting with a `::` will always refer to some identifier in the global namespace. The difference is when you have the same stuff in the global as well as in some local namespace:

```
namespace layer { namespace module {
    void f();
} }

namespace blah { 
  namespace layer { namespace module {
      void f();
  } }

  using namespace layer::module // note: no leading ::
                                // refers to local namespace layer
  void g() {
    f(); // calls blah::layer::module::f();
  }
}

namespace blubb {
  namespace layer { namespace module {
      void f();
  } }

  using namespace ::layer::module // note: leading ::
                                  // refers to global namespace layer
  void g() {
    f(); // calls ::layer::module::f();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The second case might be `X::layer::module` where `using namespace X` has already happened.

In the first case the prefix `::` means "compiler, don't be clever, start at the *global* namespace".

Answer (score 6):

It is called as **Qualified name lookup** in C++.

It means that the layer namespace being referred to is the one off the global namespace, rather than another nested namespace named layer.

**For Standerdese fans:**
**$3.4.3/1**

*"The name of a class or namespace member can be referred to after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a nested-name-specifier that nominates its class or namespace. During the lookup for a name preceding the :: scope resolution operator, object, function, and enumerator names are ignored. If the name found is not a class-name (clause 9) or namespace-name (7.3.1), the program is ill-formed."*