# What does the syntax ::function_name mean in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In the function called `::foo()` I don't understand what the syntax is for.
If it was `foo::count_all()` then I know that `count_all` is a function of class or namespace `foo`.

In the case of `::foo()` what is the `::` referencing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why prepend namespace with ::, for example ::std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925394/why-prepend-namespace-with-for-example-stdvector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` operator is calling a `namespace`  or `class`. In your case it is calling the global namespace which is everything not in a named namespace.

The example below illustrates why namespaces are important. If you just call `foo()` your call can't be resolved because there are 2 `foo`s. You need to resolve the global one with `::foo()`.

```
namespace Hidden {
    int foo();
}

int foo();

using namespace Hidden; // This makes calls to just foo ambiguous.

int main() {
    ::foo(); // Call to the global foo
    hidden::foo(); // Call to the foo in namespace hidden 
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is a good example. I just added a little bit to make it more clear in the case why you would need it.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Thank you for your input into my answer I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

`::` with nothing before it indicates the global namespace. eg:

```
int foo(); // A global function declaration

int main() {
   ::foo(); // Calling foo from the global namespace.
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a function call, not a declaration, to the function foo() in the global scope.  The :: in front of the function name means you explicitly want to call the global function foo(), and not some other version of foo() from some narrower scope.

E.g.

```
void foo()
{
  printf("global foo\n");
}

namespace bar
{
  void foo()
  {
    printf("bar::foo\n");
  }

  void test()
  {
    foo();
    ::foo();
  }
}
```

A call to bar::test() will print out:

```
bar::foo
global foo
```

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the :: you were telling the system to look at the global namespace. See also this article

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6790112/249492

Below is an example by @CharlesBailey, we're inside of the "nest" namespace. You access to "x" can change to the upper namespace depending if you specify to use the global namespace or not.

```
namespace layer {
    namespace module {
        int x;
    }
}

namespace nest {
    namespace layer {
        namespace module {
            int x;
        }
    }
    using namespace /*::*/layer::module;
}
```

Comment: Don't just share links. Add relevant info to the answer.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, thank you for the feedback. The thought was to reduce duplicate responses. I updated my answer, providing an example.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, since the answer was updated to suit the request, can you update your downvote?